# Cordova + jQuery Mobile - Much content on page = poor navigation time

Tags: performance, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an Cordova 3, jQM 1.3 application on iOS.
On the `first page` there is a lot of content. If I navigate away (through the tab/nav-bar) to the `second page` it displays the page really fast (under one second) because it has very few content.

**Every time I navigate back to the `first page` it takes a long time to load it.**

**How can I improve that? Other applications don't seem to have such a long loading-time, even on content-heavy pages.**

e: I am using changePage function, no transitions, no tap delay.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, and since there is no other question, you should mark it as answered, or update your question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your content and your application architecture.

One solution would be to not show all the content, but just a part of it and provide some mechanism for the loading the rest (scrolling down, press a button etc). This would work on single page applications (every page corresponds to its own html file) and on multipage applications (one html file for the whole app).

Another solution is to load the page when your app is launched. This would only work on multipage applications. That would mean that the page is ready, in the DOM tree and available for use whenever you call for it. This has the downside of having a bigger DOM when it isn't actually needed, and it might slow down other aspects of your app.

Finally, try upgrading in jqm 1.4 as it is stated to be faster. Try to produce your content in an efficient way (you might already do that,so just ignore me on this one if you do). Don't output your context in parts (e.g multiple html() in a for loop). Concat big parts of your content as much as you can and output it as a whole (whenever that's possible of course).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everything works smooth and fast except when navigating to a page where there is a looong list of items/divs.

I considered adding a mechanism like you mentioned. Show only 15/20 items and If the user scrolls down the page will add more items/divs. But I think it could be annoying for the user if he scrolls down, then navigates to an other page by clicking on an item and when he goes back to the first page he maybe has to scroll down again (since the page will only show the 15/20 items) to get to an other item

Comment: Well that depends. You can store some information, let's say in localStorage, that will give you how many items to show. If the default is 15 and the user has reached 45 and then moves on to the next page, then you store that information and if he goes back then you load 45. You have to be careful though and delete that information when you consider that the user should start again from scratch if he navigates deep in your app.

Comment: I would like to add that, if you use one html file (multipage app) then, if the information is loaded on the DOM and the user doesn't refresh, then it will show exactly what he previously had.